# class imbalance - applied SMOTE - next steps

Tags: r, class-imbalance, smote

I am new to ML and learnt a lot from your valuable posts. I need your advise with the following situation and guidance on if the steps make sense.
I have a binary classification problem, my dataset has a severe imbalance approximately 2% positive cases (4,000 cases) out of a total of 200,000 cases. I separated my dataset into a train and a test (80/20 stratified split). My train now has total of 160,000 cases (3,200 positive cases) and test has total of 40,000 (800 positive cases).

Next, from Train I created a (50-50) SMOTE sample which has ~9,000 positive cases (original 3,200 and SMOTE create synthetic samples of ~ 5,800 positives) and ~ 9,000 negative cases (so a total of 18,000 cases in the "new train").

next, I have developed bagged/ boosted tree based classifiers on the "new train" with ROC training criteria in R caret (I get high ROC around 0.9 which is usual). I then applied the model/s on the test set which has the original class imbalance and got the predicted probabilities (the AUC is now 0.65). I identified the optimal threshold for classification based on the pROC package for creation of the final class predictions on test dataset.

I need your advise on if I am transitioning from the trained SMOTE model with a 50/50 imbalance to the test model with the original imbalance of 50/1 correctly. is there anything fundamentally wrong in what I am doing and any suggestions on how to improve the process will be very helpful. are any corrections needed to the SMOTE based probabilities on test or is thresholding the best I can do?

Comment: You might be interested in this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193887/classification-with-a-neural-network-when-one-class-has-disproportionately-many/193960#193960

Comment: Thanks Dan...the link is very helpful. Any thoughts on the above steps that I am taking...do you see anything flawed with it?

Comment: It is hard to answer about a specific case in remote. In general, I think you should try with simple models and advance to more complex as needed. Even if the dataset is unbalanced, try working with all of it first. Then, move to balancing. If that doesn't work, generate synthetic samples. Working like that enable estimating where the core difficulty is. You wrote that you already got to sample generation, and I guess that is justified. Try to identify why the models didn't work on previous steps (e.g., no strong features, to big feature space) and maybe it will give you more directions.